# red line under R.Id.elemnt in android

Tags: java, android, gradle-kotlin-dsl

[image] the R do exist on my code same as the id's elemnt are correct , idk where's the problem , i've tried  clean cache , rebuild project and nothing has chnaged , the problem still persists

code didn't work after too many attempts  , i have still  some solutions in my pockets but...